# UITableView scroller isn't stretching

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView that contains 4 custom cells in different sizes.

For some reason, the `UITableView`'s `scrollView` isn't stretching "outside the view and then automatically returns to the maximum position", it's just stops on the maximum position and doesn't stretches.

I have no idea why, can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can You Please Explain Bit more

Comment: post the code you worked on

Comment: please give more information, screen shot , code .

Comment: @Elan by stretching I mean "bouncing"

Comment: @Cyph3r by stretching I mean "bouncing"

Comment: @SaurabhJain by stretching I mean "bouncing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by stretching you mean "bouncing", then you should check the `bounces` property and set it to true:

`tableView.bounces = true`

Usually it's set to `true` by default, so you have probably disabled it somewhere in the code.

Comment: Cool! Could you please accept my answer as correct one?